# How to vertical align text inside Text(Form)Field

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, textfield, text-alignment

I try to align the text inside my TextFormField to be vertical centered.

```
TextFormField(
  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
  maxLines: 1,
  style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Helvetica Neue', fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 14),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
    fillColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
    filled: true,
    hintText: widget.hintText,
    border: const OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
    ),
    focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black12, width: 0.5),
    ),
  ),
);
```

I tried using `TextBaseline.alphabethic` for `TextStyle`, `contentPadding top` and `textAlignVertical` to archive that but only got strange results.
For example `TextAlignVertical.top/.center` results in the same as shown in the screenshot, and `TextAlignVertical.bottom` ends in being outside of the `TextField`.
`ContentPadding top` and `textBaseline` has no impact at all.

Are there more options to try?

Here is what it looks like:
[image]

Cursor position looks perfect, just the text is not right.

Comment: I think,  it's happened for your  font family. You can try out with another font family.

Comment: Yes that was also my assumption.

Comment: Not able to produce the same issue, you can check the try with different font as @Poran said

Comment: Worked with a different font family.